# How to get an error statement when pressing somewhere else than the button

Tags: ios

I am doing simple app in XCode that has multiple view controllers, each one has a picture where the user must find a hidden object on that picture, like "Find an old camera in this room" and when you find it and click it (there is a hidden button on top of the camera in the picture) a message says, through label, you found it.

So how can I make an error message when you press somewhere else on the picture other than the location of the camera ?

Thanks.

Comment: Just add a touch down event handler to the image view -- everytime it is called, just display the message

Comment: Improved formatting and readability.